# Ajax form, .load() method doesn't work on Safari Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile, safari

I've created an Ajax Login form and once the user correctly inserts the right credentials, the page should refresh (without reload) just only the top bar (which is different in case of logged-in or guest users). So I've just inserted this piece of code on `success`:

```
success: function(data){
    $("#navigation").load(location.href + " #header");
}
```

which represents the `#navigation` area inside the `#header` block to refresh.

Now, in my case `.load()` is correctly working cross all browser except for **Safari Mobile**. **EDIT**: My problem is that in Safari Mobile it gets stuck. I don't see the block refreshing but if I reload the page I'm actually logged. So I suppose that there is a problem with the `.load()` method.

Is there something missing or should I use another method?

PS. I'm not using jQuery mobile because basically the website was already built. I've tried to implement it but I should fix a lot of issues in case. So I'd avoid that solution, not for now at least.

Comment: What do you mean, not working correctly? Any error message by any chance?

Comment: Question edited. Thank you @PierreDuc

Comment: What is #header here? Do you want to load a specific element of loaded page?

Comment: yes, I load the #navigation into the #header block. @AliSheikhpour

Comment: Does anything happen if you omit #navigation from load function?

Comment: Can you provide an answer? Thanks @AliSheikhpour